# Update user group OctoberCMS rainlab user plugin

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, octobercms, usergroups

How can I update change user's group? simply cant find it. spent couple hours.

```
$user = new User;
$user->group = 'new';
$user->save();
```

User is in relation with belongsToMany with Group.

Not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can extend User model to add `addUserGroup` method like this;

```
public function boot()
{
    User::extend(function($model) {
        $model->addDynamicMethod('addUserGroup', function($group) use ($model) {
            if ($group instanceof Collection) {
               return $model->groups()->saveMany($group);
            }

            if (is_string($group)) {
               $group = UserGroup::whereCode($group)->first();

               return $model->groups()->save($group);
            }

            if ($group instanceof UserGroup) {
               return $model->groups()->save($group);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So you can add group to user with; group model instance, model collection and string of model code.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code with string parameter and it worked.

Comment: @Surahman That was only a minor change. Your code snippet is of great help :)

Answer (score 2):

i have looked into october rainlab user class.

> User Class is linked with Group class via **belongstoMany** relation.

```
 public $belongsToMany = [
        'groups' => ['RainLab\User\Models\UserGroup', 'table' => 'users_groups'],
        'address' => [
            '\codework\users\models\Address',
            'table'=>'codework_users_user_address',
            'order'=>'addr'
        ]
    ];
```

So when you are adding User to any group please make sure you have that group already created into your database.

Table name **user_groups** : this will contain all group in which user can be assigned.

Table name **users_groups** : this is a pivot table which contains relation between user and group table.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I do know about the pivot table. But I didn't find function or property like $user-addUsergroup('groupname'); I know that I can make straight way - update(table .. bla bla ). I was sure that there is simple way. And most "October" way